Manga where the Isekai'd character dies of old age, reincarnates & then returned to Earth but can still use magic
Back in the 2010s, there was a manga about a guy who I think had recently graduated high school, who then seemingly got hit by a truck and found himself in a medieval fantasy world.
He became a wizards apprentice but never found a way home and ultimately passed away there as an old man, still wishing to go home. Then he woke up, having reincarnated in that same fantasy world but as a girl; they became a renowned prodigy and at some point did find a means to travel back to Earth.
Trying to ensure they never ended up there in the first place, the main character finds their younger self, sees them about to be hit by the truck and casts a spell to send them somewhere safe.... Namely the fantasy world, because this was a closed time loop.
They go by their family home later and find out the family thinks their younger self has gone to pursue an acting/music career, while resolving themselves to become a civil servant, and they can still use some magic, though the local spirits contracted for work are rather weak and small.
